# Customizing Ribbon configuration with Zuul/Eureka

Tags: netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-ribbon

I am using Spring Cloud Netflix Zuul along with Eureka in our environment.

I assume internally Zuul uses Ribbon to do the load balancing after obtaining the instance info from Eureka.

I want to customize ribbon configuration when used with Zuul/Eureka.

I am not sure how to configure Ribbon when using with Zuul/Eureka to change to a different load balancing strategy.

If anyone has used that can you share details on the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply specify your specific rule in configuration properties, for example:

```
zuul.routes.example-service.path=/example-service/**
zuul.routes.example-service.serviceId=example-service
example-service.ribbon.NFLoadBalancerRuleClassName=com.netflix.loadbalancer.RetryRule
```

There is much more settings that you can define:

```
NFLoadBalancerClassName
NFLoadBalancerPingClassName
NFLoadBalancerRuleClassName
NIWSServerListClassName
NIWSServerListFilterClassName
```